# Configure SonarLint for Flutter in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, dart, sonarqube, sonarlint

Wanting to clean my Flutter code, I've setup a local instance of SonarQube with the Flutter plugin. When I run my analysis, it works as expected and I get metrics like Code Smells, which is great.

Except this is not all I was looking for. On my previous projects (mostly java), I had SonarLint hooked up to SonarQube in my Jetbrains IDE and I could get this feedback in real time: variable with wrong naming pattern, functions with cognitive complexity above a certain level etc...

This was massively helpful since I was able to treat those little issues as soon as they presented themselves. So I installed SonarLint in AndroidStudio, hooked everything up to my local sonarQube instance and it's doing nothing.

It is telling me that the file is automatically analyzed, but even when I make a mistake like declaring a non-final variable, it's not saying anything unless I run a full-on analysis.

Is there any way to get real-time in-IDE analysis for Flutter code ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

SonarLint only uses official SonarSource analyzers for various technical reasons, meaning Flutter and any other third-party analyzers are currently not available.

Comment: The sonar team is working on integrating flutter in their tool set, see https://portal.productboard.com/sonarsource/4-sonarlint/c/123-dart-flutter-support. They are also seeking feedback.